# не понимаю, как работают определенные строки

Tags: c

Пользователь вводит предложение вводит слово которое хочет заменить и вводит на какое слово хочет заменить.

не понимаю как оно высчитывает размер в этой строке: `res = (char *)malloc(counter * (length1 - length2))`

не понимаю, что делает эта строка: `res[i++] = *x++;`

```
#define SIZE 80

char *replace(const char *x, const char *y, const char *z);

int main(void)
{
    char str[SIZE], a[SIZE], b[SIZE];
    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    gets(str);
    printf("Enter the word which you want to replace\n");
    scanf("%s",a);
    printf("Enter the word\n");
    scanf("%s",b);
    char *newstring;

    printf("\nNew sentence: ");
    newstring = replace(str, a,b);
    printf("%s\n", newstring);

    return 0;
}

char *replace(const char *x, const char *y, const char *z)
{
    char *res;
    int i, counter = 0;
    int length1 = strlen(z);//новое слово
    int length2 = strlen(y);//старое слово

    for (i = 0; x[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (strstr(&x[i], y) == &x[i]) //указывает на что проверитьь
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
     res = (char *)malloc(counter * (length1 - length2));//char* преобразовывает в тип char

    i = 0;
    while (*x)
    {
        if (strstr(x, y) == x)
        {
            strcpy(&res[i], z);
            i += length1; //adding newLength to the new string
            x += length2; //adding the same old length the old string
        }
        else
        res[i++] = *x++;
    }
    res[i] = '\0';
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Это то же самое что и эти команды выполнить res[i] = *x; i=i+1; *x=*x+1; То есть текущему элементу массива присваевается символ на который ссылается указатель х. После чего берем следующий элемент массива и следующий символ.

Comment: Какая-то невероятно феерическая дичь имеет место с применением `strstr` в цикле в данной функции! Это же надо было до такого додуматься. Это фактически эквивалент `strcmp`, но дико неэффективный. Зачем, о зачем?!

Comment: Кстати, функция грубо ошибочна во многом из-за такого "креативного" использования `strstr`.

Answer (score 1):

Вычисление некоего "размера" как `counter * (length1 - length2)` - совершенно бессмысленная операция, ибо очевидно, что это выражение дает неположительное значение при `length1 <= length2`. Так что и "понимать" тут нечего.

Код бессмыслен.